# Fetch data from API using headers including GUID Username and Password

Tags: javascript, json, rest, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have been allocated the task of developing a website that relies on retrieving vehicle stock data from an API. I have developed using various API's previously but I really don't have a great deal experience in this area and this API is causing me a bit of a headache! Unfortunately the company that built the API is quite scary and hostile and unwilling to provide me with any insight as to where I may be going wrong. Despite my pleading!

**Below is what is included in the API guide:**

The request will be provided via https call to a URL provided by API_COMPANY.

**Security**

All API’s will expect the following http security header to be provided as part of the request. All details will be provided by API_COMPANY. Each Dealer will have a unique OrganisatinalUnit_UID.

**Request**

```
GET
https://theurltotheapi.net/API/vehicles/stockstockListOptionModel.includenewvehicles=true
Accept: application/json
UserName: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
OrganisationalUnit_UID: UID
Host: MYWEBSITE.CO.UK
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

I have tried various methods to retrieve the API data including XMLHttpRequest as as well as the below Fetch method. But I am continuously getting a console log 403 error?

```
<script src="link_to_credentials.js"></script>
<script>
const uri = 'https://theurltotheapi.net/API/vehicles/stock?stockListOptionModel.includenewvehicles=true';

let username = USERNAME;
let password = PASSWORD;
let h = new Headers(); 

h.append('Accept', 'application/json'); 
h.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password));
h.append('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
h.append('Host', 'WEBSITE');

let req = new Request(uri, {
method: 'GET',
headers: h,
OrganisationalUnit_UID: GUID,
mode:'no-cors'
});
fetch(req)
    .then ( (response)=>{
    if (response.ok){
        return response.json();
    }else{
            throw new Error('Could not fetch data');    
         }
})
.then( (jsonData) =>{
    console.log(jsonData);
})
.catch ( (err) =>{
    console.log('ERROR : ', err.message);
});
</script>
```

I was expecting to see JSON vehicle stock data in the console, but I get the 403 forbidden error -

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).**

Comment: 403 Forbidden usually means you don't have access. Is it a restricted API that needs an API key? What happens if you enter the URL you're requesting directly into your browser?

Comment: I get the message: Authentication Credentials Missing!!!

Comment: well there's you answer :-) You need to get some credentials - check the API documentation for how to sign up or otherwise gain access.

Comment: That was my thought also. They have supplied a USERNAME and PASSWORD and the OrganisationalUnit_UID. I was unsure if my coding was wrong or incorrect/missing credentials? Their API documentation is pretty much what I have included in my message!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your authentication header to represent their example

Their exmaple:

```
GET https://theurltotheapi.net/API/vehicles/stockstockListOptionModel.includenewvehicles=true
Accept: application/json
UserName: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
OrganisationalUnit_UID: UID
Host: MYWEBSITE.CO.UK
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

But you are only passing the following headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic <user:pass>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: WEBSITE
```

Try adding the code below under this line `h.append('Host', 'WEBSITE');`

```
h.append('UserName', username);
h.append('Password', password);
h.append('OrganisationalUnit_UID', GUID);
```

and also remove the `Authorization` header

Comment: Thanks @hammy2899 but no joy! Still getting the error GET 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous)

Comment: Is it because you have a `?` in your url at `stock?stockListOptionModel`? `https://theurltotheapi.net/API/vehicles/stock?stockListOptionModel.includenewvehicles=true`

Comment: Unfortunately no, that didn't change anything. But i did change it to `Stock/?stockListOptionModel.includenewvehicles=true`
but that just resulted with: _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
`ERROR :  Could not fetch data_

Comment: Try opening your dev console and view the request which is being sent and check that all the correct headers and header values are set. If your using chrome you can view your requests in the network tab.

Comment: Thanks @hammy2899. There is nothing showing in the dev console other than _403 (Forbidden) ERROR_? Am I right in passing the Username, Password and UID within the headers?

Comment: If what you posted is the docs it is 100% header values since the request is a GET method so you can't send any POST data with it. I would ask the people who own the API to generate you some new credentials and try them since its saying Forbidden which means you aren't authenticating so the username and password must be wrong.